# Best way to implement a Rest API with PHP on WAMP web server

Tags: php, api, wamp

I own a web server running Windows ([WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)). I want to know the best way to implement a Rest API (a very simple one) in order to let a user do something.

Diagram flow:

[alt text http://img215.imageshack.us/img215/6105/flowe.png](http://img215.imageshack.us/img215/6105/flowe.png)

I have programming skills, in fact, I developed a web server in VB6 who process the queries and when it finds the command (http:/**serverIP**/webform.php?cmd=run&item=any) it does something, but I really want to develop a solution using the WAMP server.

Some people consider the solution of executing a exe when a command is detected a bad solution for security issues, but this specific project I have is for the use by some people (trusted people) who dont have intentions of hacking the server.

So, what do you think?

**Remember:**

> 1. Its not a public API, its for some people and some programs who will use
>      the API
> 2. Its a very simple one, only one command using POST or GET.

---

**Thanks**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ive just recently finished a REST API project on PHP and it was a good experience. The way I see it, the fastest/easiest  way to implement this is using the following elements:

- Object Oriented PHP
- MVC paradigm
- Create a request dispatcher

I found this link very useful when I started, it should get you going in no time:

http://particletree.com/features/how-to-add-an-api-to-your-web-service/

**Edit:**

I didnt use this framework but it looked promising: http://tonic.sourceforge.net/

Also, CakePHP supports Rest and is a neat MVC framework. If you're looking to implement in no time, go with CakePHP.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, but the tutorial you gave me use only common operations on server side like mysql querys. I need to execute programs on my server who process the data that comes from the post method

Comment: You can just follow the tutorial for the rpc part and use php's exec command (http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) for the actual program execution.